# Python sort nested lists

Tags: python, nested-lists, selection-sort

I have these lists which I have sorted in ascending order via selection sorting but it only applies to index [0]. How would I append it so it sorts the next index as well? The result that I am after is :

```
[[2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

So far i have:

```
def selection_sort(list_a):

    indexing_length = range (0, len(list_a)-1)

    for i in indexing_length:
        min_value = i

        for j in range (i +1, len(list_a)):
            if list_a[j] <list_a[min_value]:
                min_value = j


        if min_value != i:
            list_a[min_value], list_a[i]= list_a[i], list_a[min_value]

    return list_a

list_a = [[5, 4], [2, 3], [6, 7]]

print (selection_sort(list_a))
```

Comment: `sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[0]`

Comment: thanks! But I am not familiar with lambda yet :/

Comment: Basically `lambda args: expr` gives `def function(args): return expr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood right, you'd like to sort the nested lists individually and then sort the elements of the main list:

```py
print(selection_sort([selection_sort(l) for l in list_a]))
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for that but it doesnt really give me the out put i was looking for: [[2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]

Comment: Sorry I didn't test your implementation of `selection_sort`. At least `sorted([sorted(l) for l in list_a])` does that. Should the elements of outer list be sorted by their first element?

Comment: thats ok! yes, first outer list sorted then inner list sorted

Comment: I tested your implementation and it seems to work for the case you provided: `[[5, 4], [2, 3], [6, 7]] -> [[2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]`